# Doubly Linked List - appointing a tail

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Hello I have a doubly linked list without implementing, my issue is that I'm not sure how can I apoint a tail because of the constructor for Element that feels confusing to me, it is my homework so it has to be done with that constructor .
So far, my method addFirst does its job but it doesn't have a tail

I can not use getters and setters

Thank you

```
public class Element {
    private int value;
    private Element next;
    private Element previous;

    public Element(int value, Element next, Element previous) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous = previous;
    }
}

public class Liste {

    private Element first;
    private Element last;

    void addFirst(int value) {
        if(this.first!=null) {
            this.first= new Element(value,this.first,null);
        }
        else {
            this.first= new Element(value,null,null);
        }

    }
```

Comment: The head and tail have nothing to do with the constructor for the Element.  Think of it this way, you create a new element, then you decide where the head and tail should be pointing to after you have created the elements.

Comment: an Element only cares about its NEXT and PREVIOUS, whether one of those happen to be the HEAD or TAIL in your Liste is unimportant. Your Liste class is the only thing that cares about the HEAD and TAIL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check if the `last` is null. That way, the first time you put something in the list, it is the `first` and `last`. You also don't need to check to see if `first` is null when instantiating the new Element, the system will put null in for you.

```
public class Element {
    private int value = 0;
    private Element next = null;
    private Element previous = null;

    public Element(int value, Element next, Element previous) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public Element insertBefore(int value) {
        Element that = new Element(value, this, null);
        previous = that;
        return that;
    }
} 

public class Liste {
    private Element first;
    private Element last;

    void addFirst(int value) {
        if (first == null) {
            Element newElement = new Element(value, null, null);
            first = newElement;
            last = newElement;
        } else {
            first = first.insertBefore(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I missed your requirement of not being able to use setters or getters. An instance of a class can manipulate `private` variables in another instance of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple addElement method where we first check for an empty list else we traverse the list until we reach the end. Once we reach the end, we add the new Element to the list and set it's previous to the previous last Element. Finally we set the last variable to the new Element we just added to the list.

```
void addElement(int val)
{
    if(first == null)
    {
        first = new Element(val, null, null);
        last = first;
    }
    else
    {
        Element ref = first;
        while(ref.next != null)
            ref = ref.next;

        ref.next = new Element(val, ref, null); //added to the end of the list
        last = ref.next; //set the last Element to the one we just created
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but how am I supposed to get the next of ref ? Since next and previous are private and are in Element class

Comment: simply create public methods in your Element class like getPrev() { return this.previous; } and getNext(){ return this.next; }